# Minimal lateral surface of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization

> Inscribe in a given sphere a cylinder such that its lateral surface
>   (without the bases) shall be maximal.

So lateral surface is = $2 \pi rh  $ $ \Rightarrow 4 \pi x \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

Now take derivative ? or what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a set of cylinders that fit into a sphere of radius $r$. Consider those that just fit.

[image: example cylinder]
[image: example cylinder]

2. Try to parametrize them by some parameter $t$, e.g. radius of cylinder or height of cylinder or half height of cylinder.
3. Calculate the lateral surface for these cylinders in terms of the parameter $S_L(t)$.

> So lateral surface is = $2 \pi rh  $ $ \Rightarrow 4 \pi x
>  \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$

That looks like a parametrization in terms of $x$:
$$
S_L(x) = 2 \pi R h = 2 \pi R (2|x|) = 4\pi \sqrt{r^2-x^2} x
$$
where $R$ is the radius of the cylinder, and we consider $x \ge 0$ only.

Note: The above images have the cylinder axis aligned with the $z$ axis, this would be the parametrization of cylinders aligned with the $x$-axis.

[image: graph of S_L(x)]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrCX0.png))

4. Now use simple calculus to find the maximum of $S_L(x)$ for some $x^*$.

Because of symmetry consider $x \in [0, r]$. Local maxima can occur at critical points where $S_L'(x) = 0$. Otherwise extrema for continious functions can occur at the interval boundaries.

Determining the critical points:
$$
0 = S_L'(x) 
= 4 \pi \left( \frac{1}{2\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} (-2x) x + \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} \right) \iff \\
0 
= \frac{r^2 - x^2 - x^2}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} 
= \frac{r^2 - 2x^2}{\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}} \Rightarrow \\
r^2 = 2 x^2 \Rightarrow \\
x = r / \sqrt{2}
$$
Further examination would give that this is a local maximum. I updated the graph to show it.

Comment: i need to connect lateral surface formulas for sphere and cylinder?

Comment: No offense or anything, but your solution is a bit overcomplicated (look at my solution).

Comment: @Hrrhm You use a coordinate system that is better suited to  the symmetry of the problem and the optimization is avoided by knowing an optimal property of the involved function. So it is not much different. This problem can tackled in many ways. I used the OP's own ansatz and hoped to give enough information to finish it by herself.

Comment: Good point, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

No calculus required:

Let's call the radius of the cylinder $x$, and the radius of the sphere $r$. 
To simplify the problem, let $x=r\cos\theta$. Then the height of the cylinder, $h$, is $2r\sin\theta$.

So the lateral surface area of the sphere is $2\pi xh = 4r^2\pi cos\theta\sin\theta=2r^2\pi \sin2\theta$. This expression is maximized when $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, which is when $x=r\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: While I like your approach, you are using $r$ to mean both the radius of the sphere and radius of the cylinder.  If $r$ is the radius of the sphere and $R$ is the radius of the cylinder, then $h = 2\color{red}{r}\sin\theta$ and the lateral surface area of the *cylinder* is $2\pi Rh = 4r^2\pi\cos\theta\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the horizontal line through the center and the radius to the point where the cylinder and sphere are tangent.